# How to do something on every keypress, not just the first of the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have what I think must be a very simple jQuery question.

When a user creates an account on a site I am working on, the account name they create is prepended to the site address and that's the address they use to access their account in the future.

e.g. http://useraccount.thewebsite.com

When the user types the account name into the 'create account name' field on the sign-up form, I want to create a tooltip that explains what this is and shows them what the address will look like.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('input.account-name').keypress(function(){
  $("span.account-name-illustration").replaceWith($(this).val());
});
```

'input.account-name' is the input field.

'span.account-name-illustration' is this:

```
<p>Your account address will be https://<span class="account-name-illustration">something</span>.thewebsite.com.</p>
```

This works on the first keypress but none after.

So I after a little more flailing aroud, I found this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress

Which works to some extent. Except that it just continually keeps adding every keypress, ignoring what is actually in the input after deletes or placing the cursor between existing characters, etc.

So now I'm wondering, do I really want to record each keypress... or is there a way of getting the value of the input after every keyup?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're replacing the `span` with just text, the `span.account-name-illustration` selector won't find anything on subsequent calls.

You can fix this by retaining the `span` by using `text` instead of `replaceWith`:

```
$("span.account-name-illustration").text($(this).val());
```

Comment: +1 And just to clarify for the OP - it appears that keypress *is* working on subsequent calls, and it's just *appearing* not to work because of the issue @Emmett explained